# How to get data to display when selecting items from a JComBox

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jcombobox

I´m rather lost on how to get data to display in text fields when selecting something from a JComboBox. I got 2 tables in mysql which have a connection with a constraint of a foreign key (pelicula dirID and director dirID (pelicula and director are the tables)).

I got the directors names in a list so it can be displayed in the JComboBox from a mysql query but i don´t understand how i could get the text fields to change when choosing another director.
e.g
--- Titulo ---  dur-genero-pais
--- Errementari 92  Horror  Basque

```
String queryJOIN = "SELECT p.titulo, p.duracion, p.genero, p.pais, d.nombre, d.apellido"
                + "            FROM filmoteca.pelicula p, filmoteca.director d"
                + "            WHERE p.dirID = d.dirID";
        List<String> comboBoxNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
        Statement stmt = newBDD.con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs2 =stmt.executeQuery(queryJOIN);
        while (rs2.next() ) {
        String name = rs2.getString("nombre");
        String lastname = rs2.getString("apellido");
        comboBoxNames.add(name + " " +  lastname);
        }
        newBDD.con.close();
        }
        catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(comboBoxNames.toArray());
    comboBox.setBounds(45,147,204,21);contentPane.add(comboBox);
```

When I add the columns with a setText it will appear but of course not change when i change the director in the combobox and that is where im having difficulties in finding a way to connect those two things so when one changes its value the other does as well.
e.g ´editorTitulo.setText(rs2.getString("titulo"));´

This is the GUI atm:
[image: gui]

Comment: Note that we stopped writing queries this way many, many years ago. Come. Join us.

Comment: @Strawberry i´m not following?

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)